# Boost::Python static linkage

Tags: c++, boost, makefile, boost-python, undefined-symbol

I need to link *-lboost_python* statically in my project. Here's my Makefile:

```
CC=g++
override CFLAGS+=-c -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror
override LFLAGS+=-lboost_python -lpthread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lcrypto

client: clientmain.o client.o ccommand.o
    $(CC) $(LINK) ../build/datatype.o ../build/utility.o build/clientmain.o build/client.o build/ccommand.o -o \
        build/mylib.so $(LFLAGS)
clientmain.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC main.cpp -o build/clientmain.o
client.o: cclient.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC cclient.cpp -o build/client.o
ccommand.o: ccommand.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC ccommand.cpp -o build/ccommand.o
```

When *$(LINK)* is "-shared" everything is working fine. However, when *$(LINK)* is "-static" I get a plenty of linker errors "undefined symbol ...", all of them are related to boost::python. Here's some of them (the full list is really huge to post it here):

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::call(boost::python::api::object const&)':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `PyList_Type'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::call(boost::python::api::object const&)':
(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `PyObject_CallFunction'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::list_base()':
(.text+0x9a): undefined reference to `PyList_New'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::list_base(boost::python::api::object const&)':
(.text+0x114): undefined reference to `PyList_Type'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::list_base(boost::python::api::object const&)':
(.text+0x119): undefined reference to `PyObject_CallFunction'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::append(boost::python::api::object const&)':
(.text+0x18d): undefined reference to `PyList_Type'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::append(boost::python::api::object const&)':
(.text+0x1d1): undefined reference to `PyEval_CallFunction'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::append(boost::python::api::object const&)':
(.text+0x254): undefined reference to `PyList_Append'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::extend(boost::python::api::object const&)':
(.text+0x320): undefined reference to `PyEval_CallFunction'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::index(boost::python::api::object const&) const':
(.text+0x441): undefined reference to `PyEval_CallFunction'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::index(boost::python::api::object const&) const':
(.text+0x471): undefined reference to `PyLong_AsSsize_t'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::pop()':
(.text+0x5ae): undefined reference to `PyEval_CallFunction'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::pop(long)':
(.text+0x691): undefined reference to `PyLong_FromLong'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::pop(long)':
(.text+0x6eb): undefined reference to `PyEval_CallFunction'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::pop(boost::python::api::object const&)':
(.text+0x845): undefined reference to `PyEval_CallFunction'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::remove(boost::python::api::object const&)':
(.text+0x960): undefined reference to `PyEval_CallFunction'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::reverse()':
(.text+0xa4a): undefined reference to `PyList_Type'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::reverse()':
(.text+0xa8b): undefined reference to `PyEval_CallFunction'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::reverse()':
(.text+0xb11): undefined reference to `PyList_Reverse'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::sort()':
(.text+0xbaa): undefined reference to `PyList_Type'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::sort()':
(.text+0xbeb): undefined reference to `PyEval_CallFunction'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::sort()':
(.text+0xc71): undefined reference to `PyList_Sort'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::sort(boost::python::detail::args_proxy const&, boost::python::detail::kwds_proxy const&)':
(.text+0xd49): undefined reference to `PyObject_Call'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::count(boost::python::api::object const&) const':
(.text+0xef1): undefined reference to `PyEval_CallFunction'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::count(boost::python::api::object const&) const':
(.text+0xf21): undefined reference to `PyLong_AsSsize_t'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::insert(long, boost::python::api::object const&)':
(.text+0x1033): undefined reference to `PyList_Type'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::insert(long, boost::python::api::object const&)':
(.text+0x1072): undefined reference to `PyLong_FromLong'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::insert(long, boost::python::api::object const&)':
(.text+0x1095): undefined reference to `PyEval_CallFunction'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.4/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(list.o): In function `boost::python::detail::list_base::insert(long, boost::python::api::object const&)':
(.text+0x1134): undefined reference to `PyList_Insert'
```

What's wrong with my Makefile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missed symbols are certainly from libpython
So probably you can try to add -lpython2.7 or whatever python version you want to use.